# Setting up validation data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am a beginner at ML and Deep learning, i'm working on a personal project at the moment but I seem to be struggling with something very simple. Setting up my data before training.

I am using keras' `ImageDataGenerator` to set up the training, testing and validation data. The code below is what I am using.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255,
                                   shear_range = 0.3,
                                   zoom_range = 0.3,
                                   rotation_range = 15,
                                   fill_mode = "nearest",
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1/255)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1/255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, 
                                                 target_size = (64, 64), 
                                                 batch_size = 32, 
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, 
                                            target_size = (64, 64), 
                                            batch_size = 32, 
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

val_set = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(val_dir, 
                                            target_size = (64, 64), 
                                            batch_size = 16, 
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
```

```
Found 5216 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 624 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 16 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

My question is, does this automatically set up my data to be trained, tested and validated with? does it arrange the training and testing data in batches of 32 images that are all standardized?

When I try and train my network, no matter what it's architecture may be, the validation accuracy and validation loss are always inconsistent and poor

```
history = model.fit(train_set, epochs=10, validation_data=val_set)
```

This is the code I use to train the data.

Lastly, when using `model.evaluate(test_set)` I got around 90% accuracy. However when I use images found on the internet my model seems to be very inconsistent. Any tips on how to improve on this? or why this may be occurring.

Comment: Note that you are rescaling your training/test/validation images in the range 0-1 by giving the `rescale=1/255` argument in your imagedatagenerator. So when you use images found on the internet, make sure you divide it by 255 to bring them in the same range (0-1) as you trained your model with. Otherwise, the results would be bad.

Comment: Adding to above comment, the feature distribution of your dataset and the images on internet may be different. That's why there maybe performance drop. You have 5216 in training and only 16 in validation? You should use at least 10-20% the dataset for hyperparameter tuning. It will also help at the test time. You can have a look into test time augmentation too.